# QObjectPicker works strange with QCuboidMesh

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I have Qt6.2.4. QObjectPicker picks entity even I click by mouse close to entity.

For test this case you can modify [basic shapes example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt3d-basicshapes-cpp-example.html). If I click on red point on image I got "picked" cuboid. Why?

```
    // Cuboid shape data
    //   ... 
    Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker *cubePicker = new Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker(cuboid);
    connect(cubePicker, &Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::pressed, this, [] (Qt3DRender::QPickEvent *pick) {
         qDebug() << "pick = " << pick->worldIntersection() << ", " << pick->entity()->objectName();
    });
    
   //Cuboid
   {
        // ...
        m_cuboidEntity->addComponent(cubePicker);
        m_cuboidEntity->setObjectName("Cuboid 1");
   }
```

Output:

```
pick =  QVector3D(4.56187, -0.592511, 0.443995) ,  "Cuboid 1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Qt3DWindow** has render settings. It contains [QPickingSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt3drender-qpickingsettings.html) where there is pickMethod(). By default it uses bounding sphere volume picking (*PickingSettings.BoundingVolumePicking*). You should choose *PickingSettings.TrianglePicking*. It is the solution.

```
Qt3DRender::QPickingSettings *pikingSettings = view->renderSettings()->pickingSettings();
pikingSettings->setPickMethod(Qt3DRender::QPickingSettings::TrianglePicking);
```